# Google Web Fonts loading after layout has rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webfonts

I have a script on my page that rearranges a bunch of boxes into a pinterest like mosaic, using the excellent jQuery Masonry plugin. I call the box layout rendering method like this from the bottom of the page (just before ):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    wall.drawBoxes();
  });
</script>
```

I also use google web fonts like this, just after the  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Montserrat::latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); 
</script>
```

The problem is the boxes are rendered before the font has been loaded. And when the font has loaded, the boxes increase in size, making the rendered mosaic layout look like crap.

What can I do to prevent that?

Comment: You may try using $(document).load(function() { // data });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the `fontactive` callback which fires then a font has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Montserrat::latin' ] },
    fontactive: function(fontFamily, fontDescription) { wall.drawBoxes() }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add  `loading` callback - it fires when all fonts have finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Montserrat::latin' ] },
    loading: function() {wall.drawBoxes()}
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either move the web font call before the drawboxes call to load the fonts first.

I'd suggest moving your functions into a domready function. e.g.

You could also put the font call in the `<head>` to load the fonts before the DOM is loaded.

Could you just load the google stylesheet? `<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster:regular" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Montserrat::latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); 

  $(function() {
    wall.drawBoxes();
  });

});
```

Comment: May have to append that font function to the head, or just use a script tag in the head for the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `active` callback - it fires when **all fonts have rendered**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Montserrat::latin' ] },
    active: function() {wall.drawBoxes()}
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); 

});
```

For a reference on the events available, see the [webfontloader readme](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader).

Answer (score -1):

It is simpler using css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=....);
```

Comment: Maybe simplier, but blocking.